# How to check if a column exists before adding it to an existing table in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How do I add a simple check before adding a column to a table for an oracle db? I've included the SQL that I'm using to add the column.

```
ALTER TABLE db.tablename 
  ADD columnname NVARCHAR2(30);
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

All the metadata about the columns in Oracle Database is accessible using one of the following views.

[user_tab_cols](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_5465.htm#REFRN26276); -- For all tables owned by the user

[all_tab_cols](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_2102.htm#I1020276) ; -- For all tables accessible to the user

[dba_tab_cols](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_5043.htm#REFRN23276);  -- For all tables in the Database.

So, if you are looking for a column like ADD_TMS in SCOTT.EMP Table and add the column only if it does not exist, the PL/SQL Code would be along these lines..

```
DECLARE
  v_column_exists number := 0;  
BEGIN
  Select count(*) into v_column_exists
    from user_tab_cols
    where upper(column_name) = 'ADD_TMS'
      and upper(table_name) = 'EMP';
      --and owner = 'SCOTT --*might be required if you are using all/dba views

  if (v_column_exists = 0) then
      execute immediate 'alter table emp add (ADD_TMS date)';
  end if;
end;
/
```

If you are planning to run this as a script (not part of a procedure), the easiest way would be to include the alter command in the script and see the errors at the end of the script, assuming you have no Begin-End for the script..

If you have file1.sql

```
alter table t1 add col1 date;
alter table t1 add col2 date;
alter table t1 add col3 date;
```

And col2 is present,when the script is run, the other two columns would be added to the table and the log would show the error saying "col2" already exists, so you should be ok.

Comment: @Mesa very true

Comment: The comparing string in `column_name` and `table_name` always need to be in uppercase (that’s why @mastaBlasta wrote his comment) even if you created them with different casing. `create table foo (bar number);` will result in `table_name=FOO` and `column_name='BAR'`

Comment: @bugybunny Unless the column and table names are actually created in lowercase. `create table "foo" ("bar" number);`. Note that this means you can have tables named `FOO`, `Foo` and `FOo`. So groksters solution below solves the problem a little better imo.

Answer (score 41):

Or, you can ignore the error:

```
declare
    column_exists exception;
    pragma exception_init (column_exists , -01430);
begin
    execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE db.tablename ADD columnname NVARCHAR2(30)';
    exception when column_exists then null;
end;
/
```

Comment: nice & clean. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet! Can this be used for table_exists too?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "table_exists".

Comment: @grokster To check if the table exists, simply use the code -955 instead of -01430

Comment: worked perfect, great to avoid pesky maven flyway errors

Answer (score 10):

Normally, I'd suggest trying the ANSI-92 standard meta tables for something like this but I see now that Oracle doesn't support it.

```
-- this works against most any other database
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C 
    INNER JOIN 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
        ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE 
    C.COLUMN_NAME = 'columnname'
    AND T.TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
```

Instead, it [looks](http://www.builderau.com.au/architect/database/soa/Ask-Oracle-Using-the-INFORMATION-SCHEMA/0,339024547,320280758,00.htm) like you need to do something like

```
-- Oracle specific table/column query
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'columnname'
```

I do apologize in that I don't have an Oracle instance to verify the above.  If it does not work, please let me know and I will delete this post.

Comment: or try it and catch the exception

Comment: If you query the `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` data dictionary view, you'd want to include a predicate on the `OWNER` column in case the same table exists in multiple schemas.  If you know that you're only interested in tables in the current user's schema, you should use the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` view instead.

Comment: Errrr in the first snippet did you mean to write 'COLUMN_NAME' (instead of 'COLLATION_NAME')

Comment: Thanks for the catch @xDisruptor I have now corrected it

Answer (score 1):

To check column exists

```
select column_name as found
from user_tab_cols
where table_name = '__TABLE_NAME__'
and column_name = '__COLUMN_NAME__'
```

[Reference link](https://gist.github.com/davidwaterston/3755420)

Comment: This answer merely reproduces advice given in other answers without adding anything.