# Catching an exception while altering a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

I'm trying to write a command in Oracle that will wither ADD or MODIFY a column depending on whether or not it already exists.  Basically something like:

```
BEGIN

  ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD ( COL_NAME VARCHAR2(100 );

  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE MODIFY ( COL_NAME VARCHAR2(100) );

END;
```

However, Oracle complains about having the ALTER command inside of BEGIN.  Is there a way to achieve this using a single SQL command in Oracle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to put DDL in a PL/SQL block, you would need to use dynamic SQL.

Personally, I'd check whether the column exists first and then issue the DDL.  Something like

```
DECLARE
  l_cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM dba_tab_cols
   WHERE table_name  = 'MY_TABLE'
     AND owner       = <<owner of table>>
     AND column_name = 'COL_NAME';

  IF( l_cnt = 0 )
  THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE my_table ADD( col_name VARCHAR2(100) )';
  ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY( col_name VARCHAR2(100) )';
  END IF;
END;
```

If you don't have access to `DBA_TAB_COLS`, you could also use `ALL_TAB_COLS` or `USER_TAB_COLS` depending on what schema the table resides in and what privileges you have on the table.

Comment: Thanks, I acutally just found another post with a similar issue and posted an answer almost identical to yours!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351823/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-before-adding-it-to-an-existing-table-in-pl-sql).

```
DECLARE v_column_exists number := 0;   
BEGIN   
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_column_exists
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL_NAME';

  IF (v_column_exists = 0) THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD ( COL_NAME VARCHAR2(200) )';   
  ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE MODIFY ( COL_NAME VARCHAR2(200) )';
  END IF;
END;
```