# Alter Table if column doesn't exist

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, alter-table

In a table, I want to check if a particular column exists or not. If the column does not exist, I want to alter the table and create that column.

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a column exists before adding it to an existing table in PL/SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351823/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-before-adding-it-to-an-existing-table-in-pl-sql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare p_count NUMBER;

select count(1) int p_count
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
where OWNER = '<SCHEMA_NAME>' 
and TABLE_NAME = '<TABLE_NAME>' 
and COLUMN_NAME = '<COLUMN_NAME>';

IF p_count = 0 THEN
    --add your column
END IF;
```

Eventually (depending on the rights) You can use `user_tab_columns`.

Comment: The pl/sql syntax is not correct.
You can't use DECLARE without BEGIN

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can ignore the error:

```
declare
    column_exists exception;
    pragma exception_init (column_exists , -01430);
begin
    execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE db.tablename ADD columnname NVARCHAR2(30)';
    exception when column_exists then null;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add a column if it doesn't exist, just issue an `ALTER TABLE ADD (mycolumn ...);`. If the statement raises an exception (`ORA-01430: column being added already exists in table`), the column was already there and you can ignore the exception.

Answer (score 1):

look into  user_tab_columns table to check if the column exists , and do accordingly